# javascript odd syntax: c.name=i+ +new Date;

Tags: javascript

colorbox v1.3.15 from colorpowered.com has this javascript in it's minified code:

```
c.name=i+ +new Date;
```

this seems to run perfectly, should it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unary `+` operator is used to convert an object to a number by calling `valueOf()` from that object. If a number is not returned, the operation returns `NaN`

You can customize this by editing the `valueOf` function for any object, like so:

```
var foo = {};
foo.valueOf = function () { return 9001; };
console.log(+foo); // 9001
```

Date's `valueOf()` simply returns `getTime()` ([according to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf))

Answer (score 5):

`new Date` creates a Date object with the current date. The unary + operator converts it to a numeric value, which for a Date object is equivalent to using the `getTime()` method. Then it's a simple addition, `i` plus that number value.